# PDF file not opening

Tags: pdf

I uploaded several PDF files in mendeley reference manager.
However none of the file is opening, it just shows blank screen whenever i try to open a pdf file.

Comment: That app has its own support site. https://service.elsevier.com/app/home/supporthub/mendeley/ You may be better to ask there.

Comment: Did you find a fix for the issue? I am facing the same problem in Windows.